# Rails: Multiple options into a single string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make so that the user sees a number of options (I'm currently trying with check boxes) as selects multiple items, then turns into a single string joined by commas when the user submits it, ex:

```
<%= f.check_box :answer %><%= option.description %>
<%= f.check_box :answer %><%= option.description %>
<%= f.check_box :answer %><%= option.description %>
```

where :answer is an attribute in my Answer model and description is an attribute in my Option model, if multiple options are selected I want them to be saved as a single string like so:

```
"description1,description2,description3"
```

in order to save it to a single column in my database, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple checkboxes adding them the `multiple` option, this way you can have:

```
<%= f.check_box :answer, { multiple: true }, 'first', false %>First
<%= f.check_box :answer, { multiple: true }, 'second', false %>Second
<%= f.check_box :answer, { multiple: true }, 'third', false %>Third
```

Note you'll also need to specify the `false` option to "can get rid" of all the unwanted values a group of multiple check_boxes generates, something like `["0", "0", "second", "0", "third"]`, that because of the [unchecked default values](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box), so, with the last parameter in your `check_box` helper, you get just `["second", "third"]`.

So, now having just an array is easier to join those values before persiting the object into the database, this can be done directly in the controller if you want:

```
@answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
@answer.answer = params['answer']['answer'].join(',')
```

Here you get the values from the params['answer'], the form, and specifically the checkboxes you've created, as it's an array you can use `join` to *join* them with a comma `,`, so you'll get "second,third", and this way you can set the answer attribute for your Answer model with multiple checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! is there a way to call all the params in the second line? I have a variable number of options on each answer and for some reason it is not letting me save the answer to the data base can that be problem?

Comment: Do you mean to iterate over an options ActiveRecord result and get every `option.description`?

Comment: I'm currently creating a checkbox for every single option the question has, after checking the console I've traced the problem to being "Unpermitted parameter: answer", also can I add an if in the controller to avoid joining the params if it is already an string? i.e: An answer that the user responds with a text_field

Comment: After changing a couple of lines in my controller it works perfectly thank you very much! :D For future reference this the checker: if !params.kind_of?(String) @answer.answer = params['answer']['answer'].join(',')end

Comment: That's great, I still was thinking on how to do it (:.